# How I should organize my app?

Tags: android

I am having trouble developing my app, mainly because I am new to android and the best practices in terms of the app structure.

Basicly, I am looking to create an app that can create, read, edit and delete "Users". Each one of those users has a set of questions that need to be answered in a form (e.g. "name", "age, etc.). That form is divided in 4 parts that i divided in fragments in a ViewPager.

My questions:

- I have an activity to create users and a list activity to show existing users. When one decides to edit a "user", I want the creation form to be shown but populated by exisiting data (that the user can then edit). Is this the best way?
- Is using SQLite the best option for what I am looking for?
- Is there a way of defining some kind of file, or file extension for a user? I mean, in Word you have a .doc file that you can edit, read, etc. Is something elegant like this feasible in android?

I am having some doubts, but I hope to start pointing myself in the right direction from now on. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I believe yes, is there any other way of editing 'user' without a form?
2. Also yes. Other options include sharedpreferences or saving as file. But since you data is strucutured. The best option is using the SQLite database.
3. Yes, there is, but no you don't need to. The **file content doesn't change even if the ext is different**.An extentions tells a system which applicaiton is used to open such file. If this 'user' file is only used by your application only, and only used internally. You don't need to specify any extentions. Just the file name is enough. How ever, if you want other applications able to open it (example text editor), naming it "file.txt" will allow installed texteditor to edit the file.

Comment: I see, so there is no use in defining a file when you can use SQLite right? I mean, just for storage purposes?

Comment: Usually, in my opinion, you don't store the file in your database. you store the file path(link) in you database as string. Then you application retrives it from this path. If you store the user info in database, then yes, you don't need any files.

Comment: *"extentions tells a system which applicaiton is used to open such file"* AFAIK only Windows does that. Most OSs use magic numbers for that and ignore the file extension right away. In fact file extension is a CP/M thing IIRC.

Comment: Similar in android. You click on a file, intent is broadcasted, system prompts which application can be used to open such file.( or default launches). The point is, it doesn't change the content.

Comment: And Android does not uses extensions yet it knows how to open a file. My point is, extension is just part of the file name, doesn't tell anything about what's in the file. We're just saying the same thing ^^

Comment: Lol yes. lets leave it at that. Im speaking in more generic terms.

Answer (score 1):

> I have an activity to create users and a list activity to show
>   existing users. When one decides to edit a "user", I want the creation
>   form to be shown but populated by exisiting data (that the user can
>   then edit). Is this the best way?

Yes why not. This depends on tastes and the final customer.

> Is using SQLite the best option for what I am looking for?

Yes, definitely, that's what it is for.

> Is there a way of defining some kind of file, or file extension for a
>   user? I mean, in Word you have a .doc file that you can edit, read,
>   etc. Is something elegant like this feasible in android?

I don't understand what you mean by *kind of file or file extension*. If you store your info in SQLite you don't need to bother about files.